# Local wordpress site with docker redirects to https

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm trying to set up Docker development environment with the base wordpress image. Because the image has turned on $_SERVER['HTTPS'] by default, I end up hitting a "Secure connection failed" page, because it redirects to https, when I request localhost:8080 or wpsite.local:8080. I tried to turn $_SERVER['HTTPS'] off by assigning 'off' to it, but PHP won't allow me, thought the config itself does it.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
  web:
    image: wordpress:5.8.1-php8.0-apache
    restart: always
    volumes:
      # - wordpress:/var/www/html
        - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:Z
        - ./secrets:/secrets:Z
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER_FILE: /secrets/username_secret
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wpdb
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD_FILE: /secrets/password_secret
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define('WP_HOME', 'http://wpsite.local');
        define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://wpsite.local');
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'off';
      
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - wpnet
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6603:3306

    volumes:
      - wpdbvol:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./secrets:/secrets:Z

    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: wpdb
      MARIADB_USER_FILE: /secrets/username_secret
      MARIADB_PASSWORD_FILE: /secrets/password_secret
      MARIADB_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
    networks:
      - wpnet
volumes:
  wordpress: {}
  wpdbvol: {}

networks:
  wpnet: {}
```

The following shows part of the stock config that deals with $_SERVER['HTTPS']:

```
// If we're behind a proxy server and using HTTPS, we need to alert WordPress of that fact
// see also https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/#using-a-reverse-proxy
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
// (we include this by default because reverse proxying is extremely common in container environments)
```

The problem is gone when I comment out the below lines in the compose file:

```
#    define('WP_HOME', 'http://wpsite.local');
#    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://wpsite.local');
```

And remove the following line:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'off';
```

But, I wish to be able to use wpsite.local(:8080) on my local system (I have added wpsite.local 127.0.0.1 to /etc/hosts) to access the wordpress site I'm developing rather than localhost:8080, but the said problems don't let me.

Comment: did you try adding the port to `define('WP_HOME', 'http://wpsite.local')` like `define('WP_HOME', 'http://wpsite.local:8080')`?